# How to move to next fragment in PagerStrip Slidding tab with OnItemClickListener in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I am using android PagerStrip Slidding tab. I have two fragments. In the first fragment I have a listview.I want to navigate to the second fragment wen i click on the listview item in the first fragment . How do i do this? Thanks. 
Here is the OnClick Listener in Fragment1

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
     // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
    // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer,Fragment2.newInstance());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }


    });
```

//Here is my Fragment 2 which i want to navigate to

```
 public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

  private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

   public static final String TAG = Fragment2.class
        .getSimpleName();

@InjectView(R.id.textView)
TextView textView;

private int position;

    public static Fragment2 newInstance(int position) {
    Fragment2 f = new Fragment2();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}
    public static Fragment2 newInstance(){
    Fragment2 f = new Fragment2();
    return f;
}

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
   //setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
}

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView =   inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card,container,false);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, rootView);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(rootView, 50);
    textView.setText("CARD "+position);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this.
1. In the MainActivity your might already have
             ViewPager pager;
           and in your Oncreate method you also have
......

```
           pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now create the  method below in the MainActivity below.ie(The Activity which controls all your  fragments etc)

```
     public void setCurrentItem (int position, boolean smoothScroll) {
      pager.setCurrentItem(item,true);

      }
```

2. Now Lets assume your fragment1 has a listview or button.And you want to navigate to fragment2 by onClick.
   This is what you need to do

   ```
           lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int   position, long arg3) { 
       ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setCurrentItem (1, true);
   ```

   }
   });

   ```
     //Remeber int position is the position of the fragment you want to navigate to in your Adapter
   ```